# group data frame on a value for different (unknown) values

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

This is the example data frame:

```
Codes <- c("70", "70", "60", "60", "60", "60", "50")

Locations <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")

df <- data.frame(Cases, Codes, Locations)
```

I want to group and summarize the codes but for each location. It has to be a function though, that works with unknown number of locations. The result should be a data frame (or two data frames (one for each location)) that shows me **the number of cases for each code for each location**.

I know that it is simple, if one knows the location. Just filter the data frame for each location and use "dplyr::group_by" and "dplyr::summarize". But i want it as an automatic function, where i beforehand do not know, how many different locations there are.

I tried to do it with the function dplyr::group_split, but that returns a list of tibbles on which i can't perform dplyr::group_by.

This is the expected output:

```
      Codes     Location A           Codes      Location B
      70            2                60            3
      60            1                50            1
```

Thanks for answering in advance, i struggle with this big time.

Comment: Can you show your expected output? Is this what you want? `df %>%
  count(Locations)`

Comment: I guess i would need 2 columns as output. One column for each location (a and b). And each column should list the number of codes they "contain". Both from highest to lowest. I think its only possible in two different data frames, otherwise its not possible to arrange them. The problem is, that there might be more than 2 locations or maybe zero.

Comment: If you could update your post with the output you expect it would be helpful. Perhaps, you mean `df %>%
  group_by(Locations) %>%
  summarise(codes = toString(sort(Codes)))
`

Comment: edited it. maybe its more clear now.

Comment: Added an answer, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: almost. the problem ist, that it is not sorted, like highest first (dplyr::arrange(desc(x)). i tried it myself, but it doesnt work on lists. gives me an error. this is important because my dataframe is very big and the smaller codes are of little interest.

Comment: If you add `sort = TRUE` in `count` it will be sorted. `df_list <- df %>% count(Locations, Codes, sort = TRUE) %>% group_split(Locations)`

Comment: ah, interesting. thanks, Ronak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `count` and then split the dataframe based on `Location` to get list of dataframes.

```
df_list <- df %>% count(Locations, Codes, sort = TRUE) %>% group_split(Locations)

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  Locations Codes     n
#  <chr>     <chr> <int>
#1 a         70        2
#2 a         60        1

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  Locations Codes     n
#  <chr>     <chr> <int>
#1 b         60        3
#2 b         50        1
```